# My domain is with Startlogic & I am switching mail to google. I've added the MX records. Do I also need to delete a records associated with mail?

Tags: gmail, mx

Even though I haven't started receiving mail at google yet, I think my MX records are right:

```
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.     1
ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 5
ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 5
ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 10
ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 10
```

I noticed that I also have the following A records, and I don't know if they are old, current, need changing, removing, etc...

```
[mydomainhiddenforprivacy].com    23.236.62.147

webmail   66.96.130.235

email     66.96.130.235

[*]         66.96.134.37

mail      66.96.134.37

pop       66.96.134.37

imap      66.96.134.37

mx        66.96.140.70

mx        66.96.140.71
```

Do I need to do anything to these A records? I don't remember where I got them from. How can I determine if these are old and can be discarded?

Answer (score 1):

**A records** tell the world, where your server resolves.

Example: www  1.2.3.4 means, that [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) uses the server 1.2.3.4

In your case, you have a lot of extra names that all point to your server (or perhaps an older server). You need to determine if you really people accessing:

- webmail.[mydomainhiddenforprivacy].com
- email.[mydomainhiddenforprivacy].com

Another approach is that your main server is at **23.236.XXX.XXX**

Therefore, if your servers are not in IPs **66.96.XXX.XXX**, you can safely delete those entries.

As a precaution, keep a backup handy in case something breaks, and you need to restore the entries.

Comment: Thanks Luis! Do you know how long it typically takes for mx records to update for google? It's been about 36 hours, my provider says it may take up to 24, but they usually are much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the only MX records you have reference the Google servers.   The mx records associated with an IP address should go (its not clear if these are A records or MX records - but in either case they are not needed).

The webmail, email, mail, pop and imap records can go as well as you are not using these.  You probably want to leave the [*] record which is a catch-all and may be used for other things.

Provided you don't have any MX records except those pointing to Google you can leave the existing records - they won't hurt much (as in they won't stop email working) - but they do add unnecessary clutter and confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In addition and as an explainer to the other answers.  If you are using google workspace and have other records e.g. `mail.example.com` or `email.example.com` it *may* not be a problem for them to remain as long as they aren't used to access email.

If you weren't using workspace, they might be used by having the MX Record point to `mail.example.com` which is an `A Record` and then `mail.example.com` points to an IP address.